# refresh a class in Flutter with RefreshIndicator

Tags: flutter

I need to refresh my `FutureBuilder` => `Listview.builder` => `Listtile`, but i found no work around. when i do a hot reload, it updates, so there must be a way to reload whole classes? Its enIt would also be enough if I could only update the Listview.builder/FutureBuilder/ListTile. My code of my .dart:

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:ListGet/QR_Code/QR_Code_main.dart';
import 'package:ListGet/global/classes/routing_consting.dart';
import 'package:ListGet/localization/localizatzion_constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:ListGet/global/global.dart' as globals;
import 'package:ListGet/global/classes/OverviewProduct.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../main.dart';

class OverViewList extends StatefulWidget {
  OverViewList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OverViewListState createState() => _OverViewListState();
}

class _OverViewListState extends State<OverViewList> {
  String data = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: _loadproductsoverview,
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      var showData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
                      globals.jsongetitemlist = showData;
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: showData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 0),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onLongPress: () {
                                  loadproductsoverview(index).then(
                                      (value) => print(globals.productName));
                                },
                                onDoubleTap: () {
                                  print("2");
                                },
                                onTap: () {
                                  print("3");
                                },
                                child: Card(
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    contentPadding:
                                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 5, 5, 5),
                                    title: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                          0, 0, 0, 10),
                                      child:
                                          Text(showData[index]["Product_Name"]),
                                    ),
                                    subtitle: Text(getLang(context, "stock") +
                                        " : " +
                                        showData[index]["Stock"] +
                                        "\n" +
                                        getLang(context, "expiry_date") +
                                        " " +
                                        showData[index]["Expiry_date"]),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }

                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    },
                    future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(
                        "lib/global/Overview_Products/Overview_Product.json"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: "dark" == "dark"
                    ? globals.darkThemeslide4
                    : globals.whiteThemeslide7,
                height: 46,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 5, 15, 5),
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => _scan(),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code_scanner_rounded),
                        iconSize: 30,
                        tooltip: "Scan your Product",
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 5, 15, 5),
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, InterfaceViewRoute,
                              arguments: "");
                          print(globals.themeswitch);
                          main();
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                        iconSize: 30,
                        tooltip: "Enter your Product by your self",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> _loadproductsoverview() async {
    print("1");
    return await rootBundle
        .loadString('lib/global/Overview_Products/Overview_Product.json');
  }

  Future loadproductsoverview(index) async {
    String jsonString = await _loadproductsoverview();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    OverviewProducts student =
        new OverviewProducts.fromJson(jsonResponse[index]);
    globals.productName = student.productName;
  }

  // ignore: missing_return
  Future<String> _scan() async {
    await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
            "#000000", "Back", true, ScanMode.BARCODE)
        .then((value) => setState(() => data = value));
    if (data != "-1") {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, InterfaceViewRoute, arguments: data);
    }
  }
}

test() {}
```

when i swipe from top to bottom, all entrys should be updated, out of the json.

tried also this :

```
class _OverViewListState extends State<OverViewList> {
  String data = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    var showData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
                    globals.jsongetitemlist = showData;
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return RefreshIndicator(
                        onRefresh: _loadproductsoverview,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: showData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 0),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onLongPress: () {
                                  loadproductsoverview(index).then(
                                      (value) => print(globals.productName));
                                },
                                onDoubleTap: () {
                                  print("2");
                                },
                                onTap: () {
                                  print("3");
                                },
                                child: Card(
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    contentPadding:
                                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 5, 5, 5),
                                    title: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                          0, 0, 0, 10),
                                      child:
                                          Text(showData[index]["Product_Name"]),
                                    ),
                                    subtitle: Text(getLang(context, "stock") +
                                        " : " +
                                        showData[index]["Stock"] +
                                        "\n" +
                                        getLang(context, "expiry_date") +
                                        " " +
                                        showData[index]["Expiry_date"]),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    }

                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                  future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(
                      "lib/global/Overview_Products/Overview_Product.json"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: "dark" == "dark"
                  ? globals.darkThemeslide4
                  : globals.whiteThemeslide7,
              height: 46,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 5, 15, 5),
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => _scan(),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code_scanner_rounded),
                      iconSize: 30,
                      tooltip: getLang(context, "tooltip_qrcode"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 5, 15, 5),
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, InterfaceViewRoute,
                            arguments: "");
                        print(globals.themeswitch);
                        main();
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                      iconSize: 30,
                      tooltip: getLang(context, "tooltip_pencil"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Future<String> _loadproductsoverview() async {
    print("1");
    setState(() {});  // <======= Add here
    return await rootBundle
        .loadString('lib/global/Overview_Products/Overview_Product.json');
  }

Future loadproductsoverview(index) async {
    String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('lib/global/Overview_Products/Overview_Product.json'); //<== dont call the function here
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    OverviewProducts student =
        new OverviewProducts.fromJson(jsonResponse[index]);
    globals.productName = student.productName;
  }
```

Please add a setState in `_loadproductsoverview()` method. This should do the trick;

Comment: Yeah, ok thaks, but how can i update my Listview? I don´t understood what setState is doing. For me its something that can overrite things. But this is a futureBuilder, so i don´t think this works, or?

Comment: So in this case setState will run the build method again, so any changes in the ListTile will be replicated and the List Tile would update. Try it once

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this correctly:
I just have to put the `setState` without content into my function.

Comment: Right just try passing it

Comment: 1. It is a method, sorry
2. Nothing changes, even after inserting the `setState`.
```Future<String> _loadproductsoverview() async {
    setState(() {});
    return await rootBundle
        .loadString('lib/global/Overview_Products/Overview_Product.json');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `loadString` has a property `cache`, which is `true` by default. Set it to `false` and the file will be re-read.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle/loadString.html

And also swap `FutureBuilder` and `RefreshIndicator`. Then you can control state via using `setState`.

Comment: how should i swap it? Or should I just put the Refreshindicator in the Futurbilder?

Comment: I mean `FutureBuilder` should return `RefreshIndicator`, which in it turn wraps the `ListView`. So then after `onRefresh` completes you can call `setState` to update widget.

Comment: added code snippet. Did you mean it so? If yes, it isn´t working.
And sorry im not so good in things like Builder AND Future and English :P

Comment: So how I can learn you to run if you cannot go? ;)

Comment: Did yo set `cache` property to `false` in `loadString` methods?

Comment: yeah, in the `futurebuilder:` in `_loadproductsoverview()` and `loadproductsoverview(index)`